# Unity - Struggling with Dependency Injection and Monobehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection

So I'm experimenting with DI and am trying to create a GameObject Generator.
That GameObject Generator generates GameObjects inside the scene based on some internal logic.

There is variation to what kinds of GameObjects are generated and the logic can vary.

I thought that I could create a Interface and be able to create a class per "unique logic" (i.e. for every generator behaviour i create a class and can switch between generating a lot of small objects and a couple of big objects without having to use if statements, but instead the power of polymorphism).

So I've got something like

```
GameObjectGenerator : Monobehaviour
IGeneratorType

SmallGenerator : Monobehaviour, IGeneratorType
BigGenerator : Monobehaviour, IGeneratorType
```

from a logical standpoint this seems to be making sense.

The issue arrises, when transitioning from those generators.
I want to have some sort of condition, where i call a method "TransitionGenerator" from IGeneratorType
that returns a new IGeneratorType. Logically this is working aswell.

However, i want to keep track of my generated Objects (in a list for instance), because they need to be Destroyed later.
When transitioning, the List of generated Objects need to be passed to the new IGeneratorType.
This is where I find myself struggling.

The classes that implement from IGeneratorType need to extend Monobehaviour aswell because i need to make calls to Instantiate and Destroy.

But because they extend from Monobehaviour, I can't seem to create a constructor.

After a bit of research i found a lot of people pointing to either Awake/Start or to creating a Init method.

The problem is, with Awake/Start i cant pass anything and with Init, i would need to put that into the interface aswell, which doesnt make a lot of to me sense from a design standpoint.

Example code:

```
public class GameObjectGenerator : Monobehaviour{
    private IGeneratorType generator;
    public void Start(){
        generator = new SmallGenerator();
    }

    public void Update(){
        generator.Generate();
        if(somecondition){
            generator = generator.Transition();
        }
    }
}

public interface IGeneratorType{
    void Generate();
    IGeneratorType Transition();
}

public class SmallGenerator : Monobehaviour, IGeneratorType{
    private List<GameObject> generatedObjects;
    public SmallGenerator(/*List<GameObject> previousObjects*/){
        //generatedObjects = previousObjects;
    }

    public void Generate(){
        //...
        if(somespecificcond){
            generatedObjects.Add(Instantiate(...));
        }
        if(somecondition){
            Destroy(generatedObjects[0])
        }
    }

    public IGeneratorType Transition(){
        return new BigGenerator(/*generatedObjects*/);
    }
}


public class BigGenerator : Monobehaviour, IGeneratorType{
    private List<GameObject> generatedObjects;
    public BigGenerator(/*List<GameObject> previousObjects*/){
        //generatedObjects = previousObjects;
    }

    public void Generate(){
        //...
        if(somespecificothercond){
            generatedObjects.Add(Instantiate(...));
        }
        if(somecondition){
            Destroy(generatedObjects[0])
        }
    }

    public IGeneratorType Transition(){
        return new SmallGenerator(/*generatedObjects*/);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the simplest workaround to this specific case:

```
public class BigGenerator : IGeneratorType{
    private List<GameObject> generatedObjects;
    public BigGenerator(/*List<GameObject> previousObjects*/){
        //generatedObjects = previousObjects;
    }

    public void Generate(){
        //...
        if(somespecificothercond){
            generatedObjects.Add(Object.Instantiate(...));
        }
        if(somecondition){
            Object.Destroy(generatedObjects[0])
        }
    }

    public IGeneratorType Transition(){
        return new SmallGenerator(/*generatedObjects*/);
    }
}
```

This works because Instantiate and Destroy are static methods from "Object", of which "GameObject" inherits.

However this doesn't solve the problem in case one really HAS TO inherit from monobehaviour